# Ubicar menú encima de una imagen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Quiero poner el `nav` encima de una imagen y que al disminuir o agrandar la pantalla (responsive) se vea bien y guarde las proporciones. Así es como se ve ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo en mi código:

```css
.box-nav {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
  background: rgb(6, 2, 1);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(6, 2, 1, 0.8) 0%, rgba(7, 4, 2, 0.8) 50%, rgba(10, 5, 2, 0.8) 99%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(6, 2, 1, 0.8) 0%, rgba(7, 4, 2, 0.8) 50%, rgba(10, 5, 2, 0.8) 99%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(6, 2, 1, 0.8) 0%, rgba(7, 4, 2, 0.8) 50%, rgba(10, 5, 2, 0.8) 99%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#060201', endColorstr='#0a0502', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.box-nav img:hover {
  filter: opacity(.5);
}

.nav-img {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/1000x100/) no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 179px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="nav-img">
        <div class="box-nav menu">
          <nav class="nav nav-efecto">
            <a class="nav-link Active" href="#">Active</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una posible solución.
He separado el div que contiene la imagen y el que contiene el menú y les he dado un col-md de 12, así ocupan toda la fila y los siguientes div están obligados a ir immediatamente debajo.

**EDITADO**: Así está el menú por encima de la imagen, tal como pides en los comentarios, gracias.

```css
.box-nav {
  
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
  background: rgb(6, 2, 1);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(6, 2, 1, 0.8) 0%, rgba(7, 4, 2, 0.8) 50%, rgba(10, 5, 2, 0.8) 99%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(6, 2, 1, 0.8) 0%, rgba(7, 4, 2, 0.8) 50%, rgba(10, 5, 2, 0.8) 99%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(6, 2, 1, 0.8) 0%, rgba(7, 4, 2, 0.8) 50%, rgba(10, 5, 2, 0.8) 99%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#060201', endColorstr='#0a0502', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.box-nav img:hover {
  filter: opacity(.5);
}

.nav-img {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/1000x100/) no-repeat;
  
  background-size: 100%;
  
}
.nav.nav-efecto{
z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      
      <div class="col-md-12 box-nav menu">
        <div class="col-md-12 nav-img">
          <nav class="nav nav-efecto">
            <a class="nav-link Active" href="#">Active</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de los cambios que has hecho y por qué funcionan comparados con el código de la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: no funciona queda debajo pero necesito que el nav se superponga a la imagen encima nose si me explico,